# Issue with Singleton and User Object persistance

Tags: java, android, singleton

I am attempting to implement a singleton design pattern for a User Model. The issue I am having is maintaining an object that stores all the data to be retrieved at any point throughout my app. A global object.

I am not sure where or how I should be implementing a Global User Object. I retrieve the JSON Response from the server, and than create a User object from it within the AsyncTask, and than pass that User object through the interface all the way to the NavigationActivity "getCreatedUser" method.

**What should I do inside that method? if anything? maybe some type of solution to look up?**

**Here is my USER MODEL, atleast part of it**

```
public class User {

static User _user;

int location_id, group_id, user_address_zip, user_refer, user_stat,
        user_bnav, user_jguide, user_mbooks, user_minvent, user_mfeed,
        user_mupdates, user_talert, user_tmessage, user_id;

float user_owes, user_owed;

String user_nick, user_password, user_salt, user_bday, user_title,
        user_name, user_address, user_address_lat, user_address_lng,
        user_address_street, user_address_street2, user_address_city,
        user_address_state, user_phone, user_phone_c, user_phone_w,
        user_phone_cell, user_phone_carrier, user_email, user_email_work,
        user_avatar, user_signature, user_created, user_auth, user_clock,
        user_onsite, user_return, user_return_to, user_company;

public User() {

}

public static User currentUser() {
    if (_user == null) {
        _user = new User();
    }
    return _user;

}

public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}
```

**Here is the ASYNC TASK**

```
public static class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<User, Void, User> {

    Context mContext;

    public interface CreateUserInterface {

        public void getCreatedUser(User user);

        public void getUserCreateErrorMessage(String error);

    }

    CreateUserInterface callback;

    public CreateUser(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mContext = context;
        callback = (CreateUserInterface) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(User... params) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // create once, reuse
        User user = params[0];
        String url = ROUTE_USER_CREATE;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String UserJSONResponse = null;

        try {
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
            StringEntity m_stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonString);

            httppost.setEntity(m_stringEntity);
            httppost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse postResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            UserJSONResponse = EntityUtils.toString(postResponse
                    .getEntity());
            user = mapper.readValue(UserJSONResponse, User.class);

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return user;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //User user = new User();
        Log.e("USERNAME", result.getUser_name());
        callback.getCreatedUser(result);

    }
}
```

**Here is the interface methods in my NavigationActivity that implements the Interface above**

```
    @Override
public void getCreatedUser(User user) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.e("USERNAME", user.getUser_name()); 

}
```

Comment: when i create a singleton class, I create a synchronized lock on the object. Maybe this would help?

Comment: I will look into it. I am not really looking for code on this answer unless it is something stupid simple. Really I think I am missing a component, so I will look into synchronized lock.

Comment: If im not mistaken of what you want, create a class that extends [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) put the user object there and access it anywhere.